# vuejs3 updated life cycle hook not being called when state is changed

Tags: vue.js, hook, vuejs3, vue-options-api

I'm learning Vue.js coming from React. I'm confused about the `updated` life cycle hook. no matter what state I change I can't get it to run. I have a `console.log` inside the `updated` hook and I've set a `setTimeout` in the `mounted` hook. the `setTimeout` callback runs and changes the state which changes what is displayed on the DOM although I don't ever see the `console.log` from the updated hook. I'm not sure why the `update` is not firing

NOTE: I'm using Vue.js 3.

```html
<template>
    ...other components
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    state: 'initial'
  }),
  updated () {
    console.log('UPDATED!!!')
  },
  mounted () {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.state = 'changed'
      console.log('changing')
    }, 1000)
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `updated` lifecycle hook only runs when the template has been updated (was re-rendered), which would only occur when a property used in the template has changed values.

Since `state` was modified, and the `updated` hook did not run, that would imply that the template is not using `state`. Also note repeatedly setting `state` to the same value would only trigger the hook once for the new value (assuming the template needed `state`).

For example, the following snippet would trigger the `updated` hook periodically, as the timer callback toggles `state`, which is rendered in the template:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ state }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    state: 'initial'
  }),
  updated () {
    console.log('UPDATED!!!')
  },
  unmounted () {
    clearInterval(this._timerId)
  },
  mounted () {
    this._timerId = setInterval(() => {
      this.state = this.state === 'changed' ? 'initial' : 'changed'
      console.log('changing')
    }, 1000)
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/popONGj)

That said, there's usually a better way to do things in Vue instead of the `updated` hook (e.g., using a `watch` on a specific prop), but that depends on your actual use case, which isn't clear in the question.

Comment: This answer is clear, and solve my problem. thanks